# PHP Recursively scrape web page

Tags: php, recursion, simple-html-dom, domparser

I am trying to recursively parse a unprotected web directory (index of/), and list down all the files in it up to predefined depth. I have used the [Simple HTML DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) for this.

below is the directory structure

```
--index of/
---dir1/
----dir1.1
-----file1
-----file2
----dir1.2
----dir1.3
----dir1.4
---dir2/
---dir3/
---dir4/
```

it shows

```
    /dir1/dir1.1/file1
    /dir1/dir1.1/file2
```

but in next iteration, it shows

```
    /dir1/dir1.1/dir1.2/
```

This is the code

```
<?php
include 'simple_html_dom.php';

$baseurl = 'http://gawisp.com/perry/';

echo 'depth 0'.'</br>';
echo $baseurl.'</br>';

findLinks($baseurl, 1,10);

function findLinks($url, $depth, $maxDepth){
  $html = file_get_html($url);
  foreach($html->find('a') as $element)
    echo '    '.$element->href.'</br>';;

    flush();
    ob_flush();

  if ($depth <= $maxDepth){
    foreach($html->find('a') as $element){
      if(substr($element->href,-1,1) == '/'){
          if($element->href != '../'){
                $url = $url.$element->href;
                echo '</br>depth'.$depth.'</br>';
                echo $url.'</br>';
                flush();
                ob_flush();
                $result = findLinks($url, $depth + 1, $maxDepth);
                echo '.........................  '.$result;
          }
      }
      else{
        echo '----------->'.$url.$element->href.'</br>';
      }
    }
    unset($element);
  }else
    exit;
return 0;
}
?>
```

Please guide me to the right direction.

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? http://cuab.de/

Comment: @DigitalChris thank you. but i need something simpler than PHPCrawl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change you code in such a way that the current folder `$url` is not changed inside the loop:

```
// $url = $url.$element->href;
echo '</br>depth'.$depth.'</br>';
echo $url.$element->href.'</br>';
flush();
ob_flush();
$result = findLinks($url.$element->href, $depth + 1, $maxDepth);
echo '.........................  '.$result;
```